# User can create file or folder but restricted to delete in centos-8

Tags: linux, acl, centos8

In Samba share directory and file will be create by username and group name that's why I have to use sticky permission:
Chmod 1770 /testfolder 
In this permission user can create file and folder.

Anyone can help me how can i restricted to delete file and folder.

Comment: Write permission on a folder means that you can modify it, and "modifying" means you can create and delete files inside it. There is no distinction possible with this permission mechanism.

Comment: @linuxfan i just want user can upload and create folder but can't delete folder and file after upload file or folder.how can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I restrict users to delete file and folder.

Or, in other words, is there a permission such that a user can add files to a directory, but not delete them?

**NO**. The write permission given to a directory lets the user modify that directory, which means create new entries, but also means delete entries. Both operations, in fact, *modify* the directory, i.e. the list of files contained there. It would be very handy to discriminate between *adding* a file and *deleting* it - but things are not so.

---

But, depending on OS and file system, may be you can set a special attribute on a directory:

```
chattr -d +a nodelete/
```

will give the special attribute "append only" to the specified directory. "Append only" means you can create but not delete or overwrite. That will achieve, presumably, exactly what you want; see documentation for chattr, it could be your friend.